# How to change drop down based on tab selection using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a WebFOCUS report based on JS. The HTML displays data based on drop down selected. Data is sorted based on tabs. See attached Img1. [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0pFQ.png)

If I selected a dropdown option and change tab, the selected dropdown option is not seen but the default value is seen in a new tab. See attached Img2, Img3. 
[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOJmi.png)
[Img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpFlY.png)

So please suggest me how to resolve?

I am novice to JS so I have no clue what to look and change.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the drop down above the tab so it won't affect the drop down values if we switch tabs. It won't work if you create each tab as a separate page.

please check the below code I have implemented here I have added the drpdown above the tabs so toggling tab won't change the dropdown values, It might help you

```
<body>
<div>
  <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'red')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'blue')">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <p>Some news this fine day!</p> 
</div>

<div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Contact</h3>
  <p>Get in touch, or swing by for a cup of coffee.</p>
</div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanku Arun. Our reporting tool WebFOCUS will create the pages, tabs and dropdowns when we drag and drop and internally it will generate the JS and JQUERY code. There we need to create as separate pages for different tabs else it wont consider as tabs. Now I have created separate drop downs in both the tabs and I need to link them. If possible please check this link:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mEUqml0dyQ3u3DTFf3NR2FhAmJctbczt

Comment: I am not able to understand the code from the link, Maybe you can create a parent page which contains dropdown and child for tabs so it will not affect the drop downs.